# Twitter typeahead.js with webpack causing error on isArray: $.isArray

Tags: jquery, webpack, typeahead.js

Im trying to use typeahead.js together with webpack and the output file is created ok but when included in the webpage i get an error  on the line isArray: $.isArray

Jquery ($) is defined before the inclution of typeahead and can be perfectly used in other script librarys thet depend on jQuery.

When typing in the chrome console so I must be missing something in the config of webpack is my guess so any guesses or if someone is already using webpack together with typeahead how did you bundle this?

[image]